# Confidence Interval for exponential distribution using pivot quantity

Tags: self-study, confidence-interval, exponential-distribution

Let' say that $X \sim exp(\theta)$. And we have a sample of size $n$ of $X$ and we consider as an estimator $\hat{\theta} = X_{(1)} = min\{X_1,...,X_n\}$ and also consider $Y = \theta X_{(1)}$.

**a)** Show that $Y \sim exp(n)$

For this, I'm using $F_{Z}(z) = 1-[1-F_{X}(z)]^n$ = $1-[1-(1-e^{-\theta z})]^n$ = $1-e^{-n\theta z}$. So I get:

$F_{Z}(z) = 1-e^{-n\theta z}$

If I define $Y = \theta X_{(1)}$ and evaluate this on the cumulative function $F_Z$ then

$P(Y \leq y) = P(\theta X_{(1)} \leq y) = P(X_{(1)} \leq \frac{1}{\theta}y) = F_Z(\frac{1}{\theta}y)$

$F_Z(\frac{1}{\theta}y) = 1-e^{(-n\theta)(\frac{1}{\theta})y} = 1-e^{-ny}$

which is the cumulative function of an $exp(n)$, then $Y \sim exp(n)$

**b)** Use $Y$ as a pivot quantity to deduce a 95% confidence interval for $\theta$.

What I'm doing here is setting $W = \theta X_{(1)}$, so $P(a \leq W \leq b) = P(a \leq \theta X_{(1)} \leq b) = P(\frac{a}{X_{(1)}} \leq \theta \leq \frac{b}{X_{(1)}})$. Since $\hat\theta = X_{(1)}$ then the confidence interval will be

$$P(\frac{a}{\hat\theta} \leq \theta \leq \frac{b}{\hat\theta}) = 0.95$$

**c)** Evaluate the interval for the following sample:

```r
my_sample <- c(0.96,0.21,1.82,4.59,4.32,6.36,0.03,1.05,3.98,0.3)
n <- length(my_sample )
a <- qexp(0.025,n)
b <- qexp(0.975,n)
theta_hat <- min(my_sample)
conf_interval_theta <- c(a/theta_hat,b/theta_hat) # confidence interval. Is it that wide?
# Perhaps because the sample size is too small?
```

**d)** Deduce a confidence interval for the mean of $X$. For this I think I can use $1/\hat\theta$?

I'm almost sure that I solved (a) the right way, it makes sense to me. The problem is the rest, I'm not sure if my approach is correct.

I'll appriciate your help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is fine. You would get a shorter interval if a pivot was based on the sufficient statistic $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$, but yours is still a valid interval. For (d), you need a confidence interval for $1/\theta$, which you can find by rearranging the inequalities in $\frac{a}{\hat\theta} \leq \theta \leq \frac{b}{\hat\theta}$.

Comment: Thanks @StubbornAtom! I was confused with the interval being to wide. I didn´t know that using a sufficient statistic could lead to a narrower interval. Is that a property of the sufficient statistic?

Comment: Yes, it is.    It's a consequence of the Rao-Blackwell theorem. 
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rao%E2%80%93Blackwell_theorem

Comment: Well, we do expect estimators based on sufficient statistics to be 'better' than others.

Comment: @jbowman thanks!